# sql - SELECT para somente os dados recentes

Tags: sql, postgresql

> Acho que meu título não corresponde a dúvida.

A aplicação que desenvolvo insere uma vez por mês, dados referentes ao último backup em uma tabela. Essa tabela contém codigo da instância do backup, a dada da inserção e a quantidade de bytes.

O problema é que não conheço um comando ou forma de fazer por SQL um SELECT que traga somente os ultimos resultados de cada backup.

```
Tenho isso
backup   bytes    data
'x'        30  '21/12/14'
'x2'     1200  '14/10/14'
'x2'     3500  '14/12/14'
'x2'     4800  '14/01/15'


Mas preciso somente dos últimos
backup   bytes    data
'x'        30  '21/12/14'
'x2'     4800  '14/01/15'
```

Sou notavo em SQL, mas qualquer informação já é de grande valia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que algo do tipo resolve seu problema:

```
SELECT backup, bytes, MAX(data) FROM table_name GROUP BY backup
```

Comment: Sua solução funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!
:D

Comment: @Haxz esta solução só funcionaria se `bytes` fizesse parte da chave primária o que não faz sentido.

Answer (score 2):

Oi, vamos lá:

O campo 'data' é de qual tipo? Se for `date` você pode ordená-lo por de forma decrescente (hoje é maior que ontem e ontem é maior que um mês atrás) e para limitar sua busca você pode usar a função `LIMIT` do SQL, seria algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM backup ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Sim o campo é date, o problema ficaria nessa **delimitação**... Porque o número de backups é relativo ao usuário **(um pra n)**.

Comment: Provavelmente terei que criar outra query para trazer os backups sem repetir...

Answer (score 1):

Bom vi sua pergunta novamente, e o cenário abaixo não se encaixa no que você precisa... a resposta do Luis vai resolver melhor seu problema.

---

Não utilizo Postgresql, mas acredito que seja algo bem parecido com isso:

```
SELECT * FROM sua_tabela ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Troque o valor do Limit pela quantidade de resultados que você gostaria que mostrasse;

---

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct on (backup) *
from t
order by backup, data desc
```